# How to change size of textbox so that it expands horizontally across the UI with tkinter and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am designing a UI and want to implement a textbox to display inputted data. For example, when Handling Unit is inputted in the to its corresponding entry field the data will be displayed and stored in the textbox. 
[image: UIwithscrollbar]

I want the change the width of the textbox so that is expands from column 1 to column 8. I've tried changing some parameters within the grid method, but it causes some formatting errors.

Here is some code for context:

```
e1 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #origin zip
e2 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #destination zip
e3 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #handling unit(s)
e4 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #piece(s)
e5 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=13) #description(s)
e6 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #length(s)
e7 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #width(s)
e8 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #height(s)
e9 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #weight(s)
e10 = Entry(master, borderwidth=5, width=12) #class(s)

e1.grid(row = 0, column = 2, pady = 1, sticky="W")  #origin zip
e2.grid(row = 0, column = 4, pady = 1, sticky="W") #destination zip
e3.grid(row = 3, column = 1, pady = 1, sticky="W") #handling unit(s)
e4.grid(row = 3, column = 2, pady = 1, sticky="W") #piece(s)
e5.grid(row = 3, column = 3, pady = 1, sticky="W")  #description(s)
e6.grid(row = 3, column = 4, pady = 1, sticky="W")  #length(s)
e7.grid(row = 3, column = 5, pady = 1, sticky="W") #width(s)
e8.grid(row = 3, column = 6, pady = 1, sticky="W") #height(s)
e9.grid(row = 3, column = 7, pady = 1, sticky="W") #weight(s)
e10.grid(row = 3, column = 8, pady = 1, sticky="W") #class(s)

textbox=Text(master, width=9, borderwidth=5, height=7)
textbox.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=3)

scrollbar=Scrollbar(master, orient="vertical", command=textbox.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=5, column=9, sticky=NS)
textbox.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the change the width of the textbox so that is expands from column 1 to column 8.

If that is the case, you need to tell it to span eight columns, not three. You also need to use the `sticky` attribute so that the text widget expands to fill the space it has been allocated.

```
textbox.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=8, sticky="nsew")
```